# How to export a table to csv or excel format

Tags: python, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I need to export a oracle table to a csv/excel file format (along with the column headings). A solution through cx_oracle or through sqlplus welcome.

Python code from the comment:

```
con = cx.connect() 
cur = con.cursor() 
printer = cur.execute(sqlcode) 
con.commit()
```

Comment: The `csv` module is easy to use.  Please post the code you've written so far.

Comment: con = cx.connect() cur = con.cursor() printer = cur.execute(sqlcode)
con.commit()

Comment: That code doesn't do anything with "printer" (should be called e.g. query_result). You don't need the `commit()` if it's a read-only query. Get your code to the stage where you can print the query results to stdout. Then ask a question about the quite independent task of creating a csv etc file.

Comment: don't post code in a comment.  Please **update** the question with your code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

perhaps use csv module (from standard library):

```
import csv
cursor = connection.cursor() # assuming you know how to connect to your oracle db
cursor.execute('select * from table_you_want_to_turn_to_csv')
with open('output_file.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    writer.writerow([ i[0] for i in cursor.description ]) # heading row
    writer.writerows(cursor.fetchall())
```

If you have loads of data, unroll the fetchall() into a loop.

Happy trails!

Comment: Always open csv files with Python2 in binary mode. With Python3, use `newline=''`.

Comment: Good point John, added. (I just took a look at http://bugs.python.org/issue4847#msg82661)

Comment: Also, would it be possible to extract the table titles along with it?

Comment: take a look at cursor.description, in edit above, or just write out the headings as a tuple - writer.writerow(['heading1', 'heading2', ..., ])

Comment: For a large number of rows, tune [cursor.arraysize](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#tuning-fetch-performance) to get optimum performance.

Answer (score 2):

to create XLS file, use xlwt module from the [python-excel](http://www.python-excel.org/) project.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-python solution, Tom Kyte has some excellent scripts for [generating CSV files](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteflat.html) using PL/SQL (UTL_FILE), SQL*Plus, and Pro*C.