# Creating Excel or CSV reports from Oracle Database with Python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I want to connect Oracle Db via python and take query results data and create excel or csv reports by using these data. I never tried before and did not see anyone who did something like this around me, do you have any recommendations or ideas for that case?

Regards

Comment: There is an official Oracle [tutorial](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/python-with-database-11g.html)

Comment: The latest Oracle tutorial is in the cx_Oracle driver repo: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can connect Oracle db with python `cx_Oracle` library using syntax below for connection string. You should be aware that your `connection_oracle_textfile.txt` file and your .py file which had your python code must be in the samefolder for start.

`connection_oracle_textfile.txt` -> `username/password@HOST:PORT/SERVICE_NAME`(you can find all of them but username and password in tnsnames.ora file)

```
import cx_Oracle as cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

def get_oracle_table_from_dbm(sql_text):
    if 'connection_oracle' not in  globals():
        print('connection does not exist. Try to connect it...')
        f = open('connection_oracle_textfile.txt', "r")
        fx = f.read()         
     ####
     global connection_oracle
     connection_oracle = cx_Oracle.connect(fx)
     ####
     print('connection established!!')

     print('Already have connection. Just fetch data!!')
     return pd.read_sql(sql_text, con=connection_oracle)

 df=get_oracle_table_from_dbm('select * from dual')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other stackoverflow answers to this, e.g. [How to export a table to csv or excel format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669773/how-to-export-a-table-to-csv-or-excel-format).  Remember to tune [cursor.arraysize](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#tuning-fetch-performance).

You don't strictly need the pandas library for to create csv files, though you may want it for future data analysis.

The cx_Oracle documentation discussions [installation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html), [connection](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html), and [querying](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html), amongst other topics.

If you want to read from a CSV file, see [Loading CSV Files into Oracle Database](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#loading-csv-files-into-oracle-database).